# Looking to use the ISNULL function to check if an image is active else select max

Tags: sql, select, case, isnull

If an image is marked as active and a person clicks on the link they should be taken to the active image otherwise they should be taken to the (MAX) most recent image uploaded. My first select works but not entirely.

Here's my select:

```
    select
    b.image_id, b.active, c.id as event_id
from event.dbo.lite() a
left outer join event.dbo.dia_tracker b on a.code = b.patient_id 
    and image_id = (select max(image_id) from event.dbo.dia_tracker where patient_id = {$patient->hex})
left outer join event.dbo.ev c on a.code = c.patient_id and c.task_id in ('WR','RC') and c.status<>0
where a.code = {$patient->hex}
```

Here's my new select that I need a bit of help with.

```
select 
    image_id, 
    active,
    case when active <>1 than image_id = (select max(image_id) from event.dbo.dia_tracker where patient_id = 'DSMA')
from event.dbo.dia_tracker

where active = '1' and image_id = (select max(image_id) from event.dbo.dia_tracker where patient_id = 'DSMA')
```

it's a bit of a mess atm. I was thinking I could use isnull to accomplish more in less lines of code.

update:

```
select 
    *,
    ISNULL(active,image_id) as  image
from event.dbo.dia_tracker

    where active = '1' and image_id = (select max(image_id) from event.dbo.dia_tracker where patient_id = 'DSMA')
```

Still need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier if you would post all relevant DDL and sample data, but you can try something like this to get your `image_id`

```
SELECT COALESCE(
  (SELECT image_id FROM dia_tracker WHERE patient_id = 'DSMA' AND active=1), 
  (SELECT MAX(image_id) FROM dia_tracker WHERE patient_id = 'DSMA')
) AS image_id
```

And if it (`image_id`) uniquely identifies the row you're looking for you can try

```
SELECT * FROM dia_tracker
WHERE image_id = (SELECT COALESCE(
  (SELECT image_id FROM dia_tracker WHERE patient_id = 'DSMA' AND active=1), 
  (SELECT MAX(image_id) FROM dia_tracker WHERE patient_id = 'DSMA')
) AS image_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

if active = 1 then sub-query is grouping and result taken to the active image otherwise most recent image.

```
select *, t1.image_id as  image
from event.dbo.dia_tracker t1
WHERE EXISTS (select 1
              from event.dbo.dia_tracker t2                      
              where t2.patient_id = 'DSMA'
              group by case when t2.active = '1' then t2.image_id end
              having MAX(t2.image_id ) = t1.image_id)
```